# Laravel post form is not submitting?

Tags: php, laravel, forms

I want to make a form where you select what exercises you have done and afterwards add them to the database, but the problem is that I can't even submit my post form. The button does nothing when it is pressed.

This is my view file:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

    @section('content')
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">



        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-body">
                <h2>Excercise - {{$excercises[0]->hnro}}</h2>
                <hr>
                <div class="col-md-10">
                @if (session('error'))
                    <div class="alert alert-danger">
                        {{ session('error') }}
                    </div>
                @endif
                    @if (session('success'))
                        <div class="alert alert-success">
                            {{ session('success') }}
                        </div> 
                    @endif
                    
                <form class="form-horizontal" name="form" method="POST" action="{{ route('storeScores') }}">
                
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                        <input type="url" name="url" id="url" class="form-control" placeholder="Copy the URL here" required autofocus>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                
    </div>

    @foreach($excercises as $excercise)

    <div class="row">
    <div class="form-group col-md-3 col-md-offset-1">
    <select class="form-control" id="select{{$excercise->tnro}}" name="teht[]" required>
    <option value="">Excercise {{$excercise->tnro}}</option>
    <optgroup label="Choose your points">
    @for ($i=0; $i<=$excercise->maxpist;$i++)
    <option value="{{$i}}">{{$i}} points</option>
    @endfor
    </optgroup>


    </select>
    </div>
    </div>
    @endforeach



    <div class="form-group row">
                        <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1">
                            <button type="submit" name="save" class="btn btn- 
   primary">Tallenna</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                            <input type="hidden" name="hnro" value="">
                            <input type="hidden" name="student_id" value="">

                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
    </div>
    @endsection
```

This is my route:

```
Route::get('/addscoreform','HarkkaController@showExcercises');
Route::post('/addscoreform','HarkkaController@storeScores')->name('storeScores');
```

And this is my controller:

```
public function storeScores(Request $request)
{
    return redirect()->back()->with('success','Form has been sent...');
}
```

My problem is that I can't even display the success message after submit! It's like the button doesn't work!

Comment: I don't see any <form> your form here</form> tag there, how can it fire if you doesn't wrap the button inside form tag?

Comment: The button is wrapped in a <form> tag. You can see it in the view.

Comment: Are you using vscode? If so install blade snippets extensions and it will help you format the html/php/blade and see errors more easily.

Comment: Yes I am using vscode. I installed the extension and it makes the code more clear for sure, but it doesn't display any errors so I don't really know where to start to find the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you have tag nesting issues.

```
<form ...>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <input type="url" name="url" id="url" class="form-control" ...>
    </div>
  </div>          
</div>
...
</form>
```

What is the third  closing? Ensure that the opening and closing tags are nested properly.

A few things which might help organize this better and make it easier to maintain are to eliminate any tags you can, and to break things down into smaller subviews and include statements as much as possible. Subviews are described at https://laravel.com/docs/master/blade#including-subviews.

Comment: The ending div is for   <div class="col-md-10"> . Well, thanks for the tip, I'll check it out..

Comment: In that case, you should move the  <div class="col-md-10"> to inside the <form> tag which would get the nesting in line. Think of each tag as a container. Either the form needs to completely contain that div, or that div needs to completely contain that form.

Comment: Actually, I needed to move the </div> to the bottom and now it works! Omg I can't believe I missed that. The forms CSS is a bit wonky now, but I'll try to fix it.